# How to get AttributedString attributes to show in NSTextView?

Tags: swiftui, appkit

I've created a custom view using `NSTextView` like the below.

```
struct CustomNSTextView: NSViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: AttributedString // automatic memberwise intializer

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
        var textFrame: NSRect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 2, height: 50))
        var textView: NSTextView = NSTextView(frame: textFrame)
        textView.backgroundColor = .white
        return textView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) {
        nsView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(text))
    }
}
```

and then I pass in an `AttributedString` with some colorings like below.

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    @State private var test = transformText(string: "testing attributed string tag conversion. #tagging")


    var body: some View {
        CustomNSTextView(text: $test)
    }
}


func transformText(string: String) -> AttributedString {
    var aString = AttributedString(string)
    var splitString = string.split(separator: " ")
    var tags: [String] = []
    for str in splitString {
        if str.hasPrefix("#") {
            tags.append(String(str))
        }
    }

    // now set the foregroundcolors
    for tag in tags {
        var range = aString.range(of: tag)!
        aString[range].foregroundColor = .blue
    }

    return aString
}
```

I'd expect the string to be colored for #tagging but instead it's just all black like normal text. But when using a regular SwiftUI `Text` and passing in the attributes it works.

[image]
Is there some property I need to set on `NSTextView` to get an `AttributedString` to render that I am missing?

edit: adding regular Text example.
[image]

Comment: You have to apply the `appKit` scope. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributescopes/3816193-appkit

Comment: Oh amazing, applying `.appKit` before the foreground color works. Thank you @matt